# Mostrar si hay o no archivos en un directorio con cmd y .bat

Tags: cmd, batch, .bat

estoy haciendo un script con cmd en Windows 10 en un archivo .bat. El enunciado dice así:

*Crea un archivo bat llamado checkdir.bat que nos dice si el directorio pasado como parámetro contiene ficheros o no, mostrando respectivos mensajes.*

Como lo puedo enfocar? Con un IF, FOR...?
He pensado que un archivo tiene que ser mayor tamaño que cero, y tambien tener una extensión.
Puedo enfocarlo de la siguiente manera:

**Si existen archivos en la carpeta con tamaño mayor que 0 - mostrar "Si, existen ficheros en esa carpeta" - Si no existen - "No, no hay ficheros en esa carpeta."**

Cuál sería el código?
Muchas Gracias!

Este es mi código que llevo intentado por ahora:

```
@echo off
cls
set /P d= Indica el directorio para mostrar los ficheros:  
forfiles /p %d% 2>NUL
if %errorlevel%==1 goto no
if %errorlevel%==0 goto ok
:ok
echo Existen ficheros en este directorio.
goto fin
:no
echo No existen ficheros en este directorio.
:fin
pause
```

Creo que se puede simplificar aún más, y lo he hecho de una forma extraña, aunque funciona.

Comment: Que tal compañero, te invito a leer la sección sobre [cómo elaborar una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). En ella encontrarás algunos consejos entre los que se incluye el mostrar un [ejemplo mínimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Si te es posible comparte lo que haz intentado, e incluye dudas referentes a tu código de esta manera facilitas la ayuda que se te pueda brindar. Las preguntas que piden por código directamente no son bien recibidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas un par de loops, uno para iterar en los archivos del directorio y el otro para iterar en los atributos del archivo y así obtener su tamaño y averiguar si es superior a 0.

El siguiente script que hice a modo de ejemplo valida lo siguiente:

- Si el directorio existe especificado.
- Si la carpeta contiene archivos o no .
- Si la carpeta contiene archivos de tamaño superior a los 0 bytes.

En caso de que no hayan archivos o de que los archivos no superen los 0 bytes, el script informará que el directorio no contiene archivos.

Para ejecutar el script debes usar el siguiente comando, en el que "C:/Directorio" es el directorio a comprobar:

`start Nombre_Script.bat "C:/Directorio"`

> Renombrar script y cambiar directorio.

---

*Script bat:*

```
@echo off

REM Comando para lanzar el script:
REM >> start NOMBRE_SCRIPT.bat "C:/Directorio"

REM Controla si el directorio especificado existe
if exist %1 (

    REM Itera en los archivos del directorio
    for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a /b /s %1') do (
        
        REM Controla la grandeza de los archivos
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%s in ('%%f') do (

            REM Controla si hay archivos superiores a los 0 bytes
            if %%~zs GTR 0 (
                echo El directorio contiene archivos
                goto end
            )
        )
    )
    REM Se ejeccuta en caso de que ningun archivo supere los 0 bytes
    echo El directorio no contiene archivos

) else (
    echo El directorio especificado no existe
)

:end
pause
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! :)